# How to execute protractor tests in a specific order

Tags: angular, testing, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I've created protractor tests for my project, they run just fine, however, i would like to execute them in a specific order.

By default, protractor tests execute in this order, as specified in protractor.conf.js:

```
specs: [
    './e2e/entities/*.spec.ts',
    './e2e/account/*.spec.ts',
    './e2e/admin/*.spec.ts',
],
```

When i change this part, to execute only one test, for example this:

```
specs: [
    './e2e/entities/client-customer.spec.ts'        
],
```

It still execute all the tests in alphabethic order, ignoring the specs: [] part.

Some people suggested that i could fix this by prefixing a number to each tests, like:

> Blockquote 1-client-customer.spec.ts

But this not only would be a non definitive solution, but also doesn't work!! It still execute them alphabetically, ignoring the number prefix.

Does anyone has an idea on this? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: one of the main idea is make tests isolated. So, maybe you should solve this issue instead of creating bicycle? Also, after some time you will want to run your tests in parallel so better to make them isolated right now)

Comment: @Oleksii So, you mean i should put each test inside a folder and call them in the order i want?

Comment: @RohrFacu Oleksii is trying to say that every spec file should be able to pass by itself without interaction from other spec files. If they rely on each other, they should ideally be in the same spec file.

Comment: Even tough your answers didn't help me for this particular case, they are the best long term solutions, so thank you both @Oleksii & Ben Mohorc